# How to validate Command injection

Tags: java

I am passing 3 arguments to main java method.

arg[0] is user command like copy file or similar. but don't want to include Rmdir,move,format etc. there could be more cmd like this.
arg[1] is remote directory name/location
arg[2] is local directory name/location

checkmarx tool is suggesting  to properly validate these arguments.
what is the best way to validate all these arguments?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To get the help you desire, and avoid dwonvotes, it would be best if you review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring-Web's HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(Variable) to sanitize parameters before passing to method.

Also, you can try Variable=Variable.replace("'", ""); with it as well.

Use both on parameters before passing to method.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this option.